# query SNMP community string permission

Tags: string, powershell, cmd, command-line-interface, snmp

i'm seeking a solution to query SNMP community string permissions. For example, community name would be MyHouse with a Read only permission. How could I query this information in a CLI or PowerShell format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community string is usually stored in SNMP agent configuration file. If you are using NET-SNMP Agent the configuration is stored in snmpd.conf file. For more information please refer to NET-SNMP documentation. Some other agents store it in database. So it depends on agent implementation.